# How can I see which thumbnails my Wordpress theme is actually using?

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

In short, I'd like to remove some of the unnecessary thumbnails that my theme/Wordpress creates. I have Media Cleaner Pro, however I was wondering if there was a way to see which thumbnails are actually being used, so I know which sizes are redundant so I can uncheck them and ensure they don't get generated in future. Also, I use Divi and WooCommerce if that makes any difference.

Any help on this would be gladly appreciated - thanks!